# How to return 1 of many possibilities from method

Tags: c#

I have a login procedure, which can result in multiple results:

- User not activated
- Unknown username
- Invalid password
- Valid password

I'm thinking about how I would design the method. I see these options

- One method for each possibility (like IsUserActivated, IsUsernameKnown..). This seems to violate "Tell don't ask" principle, I don't know I just don't like it.
- Throw custom exception for each possibility (like UserNotActivatedException, UserUnknownException..). This also seems wrong to me.
- Return custom ValidationResult class
- Return custom enum

Ideas? :-)

Also feel free to edit the subject (and tags)

Answer (score 9):

I would go with the last, you don't need a full blown class, an enum is enough.

However, do you plan on telling the user that their password is wrong?  This allows a hacker to verify they are using a correct login and just need to find the right password.  The more secure option is to always tell the user their login was unsuccessful and not specify whether it was the username or password.

Answer (score 2):

I would return a custom Enum. This is a textbook case for using Enums.

As you expect each result to happen at a certain time, these results are not unexpected (i.e. they are expected), so Exceptions are simply an overhead that you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a simple status, than I would definitely go for an enum, because enums are self documenting.

Answer (score 0):

I would return:

```
class ValidationResult
{
    enum{ not_activated, unknown_user, invalid_password, success} status;
    String session_id; // used if the user is valid

}
```

And call it like this:

```
result = login(userName, password);
if (result.status == success) then 
 ...
```

The session ID can then be used whenever the user needs to interact with the system